# Security config apply authentication for all matchers when adding 'cors disable'

Tags: java, spring-security

When I configure my security like that:

```java
    httpSecurity
        .anonymous()
            .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/**/mes-actus/**").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
            .and()
        // make sure we use stateless session; session won't be used to
        // store user's state.
        .addFilterBefore(headerUserRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

it authenticates only routes that contains `mes-actus` and permit all others, that good!

But when I add this instruction: `.cors().and().csrf().disable()` then it demands authentication for all without exception.

In other words **`.antMatchers("/**/mes-actus/**").authenticated()`** is ignored.

if i remove .`cors().and().csrf().disable()` i got 403 forbidden

Comment: What error did you get? 401 or 403?

Comment: i got 403 forbidden

Comment: Did you get 403 with `.cors().and().csrf().disable()`, too?

Comment: no, i didn't get when adding those lines, but i loose the filter by route

Answer (score -1):

Can you try the code below: it allows all `/**/mes-actus/**` calls:

```java
http
    .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**/mes-actus/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
http
    .csrf().disable()
    .cors().disable();
```

Comment: @dur, i want do the reverse of that, permit for all except '/**/mes-actus/**' to authenticate

Comment: @Mirlo I know it. This isn't my answer.